# How would I Update an sql database I made with flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy to store users and posts. The entire database is stored in this users.sqlite3 file. Let's say this is my user class:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    status = db.Column(db.String(100))
    about = db.Column(db.String(500))
```

Now let's say I wanted to add another column like a favorite number or something. I would have to add `number = db.Column(db.Integer())`. But then it won't work because the file is already generated and now I'm saying that there's another column that doesn't exist in there. So I would have to delete all the data in that file and start with an empty database every time I want to update it.

Is there anyway to get around this? Could I do something to just make it so that those other values were empty when I added them in?

Comment: https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

This is called a database migration. You basically need 2 steps-

1. Update your model file to the new state (add your column).
2. Run a "migration" - which is a one time change to update the EXISTING database to match the new model (in this case, it would be `UPDATE TABLE ADD COLUMN ...`)

sqlalchemy provides the `alembic` package to help with migrations, you just need to generate them and ensure they get run on each deploy to keep your database schema up-to-date with your code.